# Saving Image to disk using .net core on Ubuntu (GCloud Compute Engine)

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core

I am running some code that needs to save an Image on the disk. 
I am using .net core 1.0 on a google compute ubuntu instance, and ImageProcessorCore library for the Image objects.

This is the code that fetches the image from a Cloud Storage bucket into a byte array and tries to save it on disk.

```
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

        if (!File.Exists(file))
        {
            byte[] bytes = mediaAdapter.GetMedia(Id, Resolution);

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                Image image = new Image(stream);
                using (FileStream save = File.Create(file))
                    image.Save(save);
            }
        }
        using (FileStream read = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            Image img = new Image(read);
            return new BoundingRect(img.Width, img.Height);
        }
```

This code runs perfectly on a windows machine running .net core but stops executing on my compute engine with no exceptions thrown.

PS: Directory.CreateDirectory(dir); creates the directory on the compute engine.

Any help would be appreciated. thx

Comment: What version of ImageProcessorCore are you using and where exactly did you get it?

Comment: You don't need the `Image` class to save binary data to disk. You only need it if you want to *process* the image. Just use `File.WriteAllBytes(file,bytes)`

Comment: Thanks you for your input, it was a permission issue that i didn't take care of! i needed to chown the directory i was saving in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was related to permission issues on the directory i was trying to save the files in. (chown fixed the problem)

Answer (score 0):

It's showing that it's only supported in Windows.

```
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePath);
var thumbimage = image.GetThumbnailImage(64, 64, new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(() => false), IntPtr.Zero);
thumbimage.Save(thmfilepath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).